# How to find a set of generators with the smallest number of elements in a permutation group?

Tags: group-theory

Given a permutation group with many generators

```
g=PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{}],Cycles[{{3,5,7}}],Cycles[{{3,7,5}}],Cycles[{{2,3},{5,7}}],Cycles[{{2,3,5}}],Cycles[{{2,3,7}}],Cycles[{{2,5,3}}],Cycles[{{2,5,7}}],Cycles[{{2,5},{3,7}}],Cycles[{{2,7,3}}],Cycles[{{2,7,5}}],Cycles[{{2,7},{3,5}}],Cycles[{{1,2},{5,7}}],Cycles[{{1,2},{3,5}}],Cycles[{{1,2},{3,7}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3,5,7}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3,7,5}}],Cycles[{{1,2,5,7,3}}],Cycles[{{1,2,5}}],Cycles[{{1,2,5,3,7}}],Cycles[{{1,2,7,5,3}}],Cycles[{{1,2,7}}],Cycles[{{1,2,7,3,5}}],Cycles[{{1,3,2}}],Cycles[{{1,3,5,7,2}}],Cycles[{{1,3,7,5,2}}],Cycles[{{1,3},{5,7}}],Cycles[{{1,3,5}}],Cycles[{{1,3,7}}],Cycles[{{1,3},{2,5}}],Cycles[{{1,3,2,5,7}}],Cycles[{{1,3,7,2,5}}],Cycles[{{1,3},{2,7}}],Cycles[{{1,3,2,7,5}}],Cycles[{{1,3,5,2,7}}],Cycles[{{1,5,7,3,2}}],Cycles[{{1,5,2}}],Cycles[{{1,5,3,7,2}}],Cycles[{{1,5,3}}],Cycles[{{1,5,7}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{3,7}}],Cycles[{{1,5,7,2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,5,2,3,7}}],Cycles[{{1,5,2,7,3}}],Cycles[{{1,5,3,2,7}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,7}}],Cycles[{{1,7,5,3,2}}],Cycles[{{1,7,2}}],Cycles[{{1,7,3,5,2}}],Cycles[{{1,7,3}}],Cycles[{{1,7,5}}],Cycles[{{1,7},{3,5}}],Cycles[{{1,7,5,2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,7},{2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,7,2,3,5}}],Cycles[{{1,7,2,5,3}}],Cycles[{{1,7,3,2,5}}],Cycles[{{1,7},{2,5}}]}];
```

`GroupGenerators[g]` gives a set of generator with many redundant elements. In fact, `g` can be generated with `{Cycles[{{1, 5, 7}}], Cycles[{{5, 2, 3}}]}`.

```
g == PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 5, 7}}], Cycles[{{5, 2, 3}}]}]
```

How can I find `{Cycles[{{1, 5, 7}}], Cycles[{{5, 2, 3}}]}` in mathematica? Hope to see a method as fast as possible.

Comment: I believe you need the Schreier-Sims algorithm. [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm) and it should be able to come up with a set of minimal generators in polynomial time. Kind of complicated to implement though.

Comment: [See this also](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4481325/775158)

Answer (score 2):

This method randomly shuffles the group elements and then goes through them, adding an element only if it is not reachable from the group so far. I run this many times with different shuffles and choose the list of generators with a small `LeafCount`.

```
reduceGroupAttempt[g_] :=
 Module[{
   elements = RandomSample@GroupElements@g,
   dictionary = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"]},
  dictionary["Append", elements[[1]]];
  Do[
   If[! GroupElementQ[PermutationGroup[Normal[dictionary]], e], 
    dictionary["Append", e]], {e, elements}
   ];
  GroupGenerators@PermutationGroup@Normal@dictionary
  ]

reduced = First@MinimalBy[Table[reduceGroupAttempt[g], {50}], LeafCount]
h = PermutationGroup[reduced];

isomorphicGroupsQ[group1_, group2_] := 
 Length[ResourceFunction["FindGroupIsomorphism"][group1, group2, 1]] == 1

isomorphicGroupsQ[g, h]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268708/21532), and use this function directly:

```
CanonicalPermutationGroup[G_] := 
 Module[{gens = GroupGenerators[G], tmp}, 
  If[PermutationGroup[gens] == 
      PermutationGroup[tmp = DeleteCases[gens, #]], gens = tmp] & /@ 
   gens; PermutationGroup[gens]]
```

In your cases:

```
CanonicalPermutationGroup[g]
```

> PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,7,3,2,5}}],Cycles[{{1,7},{2,5}}]}]